# How to stop fake locations using LocationClient on Android

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

I'm working on a GPS game, similar to geocaching, which requires the devices accurate GPS cordinates.

I am using LocationClient and not LocationManager.

Early in testing, a friend pointed out that the location can be faked using free apps on the play store. A bit of research shows that without root, these apps require Mock Location to be enabled. So I started with a simple check to see if mock location was enabled, and if it was then the app would not allow the user to play until it is disabled.

This got me thinking though, users who are rooted could still fake their location without having mock location enabled, however most of these apps still have the MOCK_LOCATION permission regardless if the device is rooted or not. So I used a method that detects any apps that require Mock Location. The problem is, even on my non rooted Note 3, there appears to be several pre-installed apps that require Mock Location for some reason, which then prevents game play. So this solution wont work.

Is there any other way to check if a location might be faked using LocationClient?

Answer (score 1):

In API 18+ you can use [Location.isFromMockProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#isFromMockProvider()) to check if a particular location is mocked. This flag will be set to true if an app is providing mocked (fake) locations or if you are using a mock provider in your own app.

Of course, rooted phones can bypass this.

Answer (score -1):

In your device, go to settings >> developer options >> allow mock locations

This option must be checked in you device that's why you are getting mock location updates. To stop receiving just uncheck it.

In your code, you can also set `mLocationClinet.setMockMode(false);` in your `onCreate()` method of Location tracking activity.

I hope it works :)

Comment: Please read my post fully, I'm not getting mock location updates, I'm trying to prevent users from spoofing their location. I'm successful in checking if mock location is enabled and preventing the app from running if it is, but I need a secondary check for rooted devices, since rooted users do not need Mock Location enabled in order to spoof their location.

Comment: As far as i know not possible. Nevertheless they are outliners , i'll not put to much effort on this. If you really want to do it , check if user is rooted , and if he is so , check for the more popullar mocking app. If they are installed , warn the user.